# jQuery Image Upload to MVC5

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I currently have the following code within my server side API:

```
 // Enable both Get and Post so that our jquery call can send data, and get a status
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
        {
            // Get a reference to the file that our jQuery sent.  Even with multiple files, they will all be their own request and be the 0 index
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

            // do something with the file in this space 
            // {....}
            // end of file doing

            // Now we need to wire up a response so that the calling script understands what happened
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = new { name = file.FileName };

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;

            // For compatibility with IE's "done" event we need to return a result as well as setting the context.response
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

I use the following jQuery to call it:

```
$(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/Upload",
            limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
            sequentialUploads: true,
            progressInterval: 100,
            maxChunkSize: 10000,
            add: function (e, data) {
                $('#filelistholder').removeClass('hide');
                data.context = $('<div />').text(data.files[0].name).appendTo('#filelistholder');
                $('</div><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:0%"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
                $('#btnUploadAll').click(function () {
                    data.submit();
                });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                data.context.text(data.files[0].name + '... Completed');
                $('</div><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:100%"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#overallbar').css('width', progress + '%');
            },
            progress: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem I am having is, I don't understand where I can grab the completed uploaded file. As when I add a breakpoint this one function get's called 100's of times on one image upload.

Could someone please give me help on why it's called so much?

And I suppose the best way to ensure that it is only been an image uploaded (no exe, viruses etc).

I just want to upload the file, confirm it's an image, resize the file and save to by database as a Base64 string or to the file system either or?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, add details to the question being specific at some points: which function gets called 100 times? (add, done, progressall, progress, fileupload... which one?).

Comment: File upload that seems to be the issue, I just dont know how to get thei file and save it

Comment: I can see you are doing a Response.Write like if you were trying to Download the file After upload it. Please check this example: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/WKNQ120113-How-to-upload-a-file-in-MVC4.html (It also validates extension file names).